# Laravel getting nested foreach values out of foreach

Tags: php, jquery, forms, laravel, foreach

```
@foreach ($getDocs as $key => $docs)
    @foreach ($docs->doc_user as $key1 => $users)
        @foreach ($users->details as $key2 => $value2)

            //Accessing different things here

        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I have `form` outside of the above `foreachs`, I need the id of `$user` like `$user->id`, I tried **hidden field in the above** `foreachs`, And accessed the the value of the that hidden field and gave that value to the hidden field in the form.

**That problem with the above method is that the `$user->id` was the same for every record**.

How can i solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `pluck` like this

```
@foreach ($getDocs as $key => $docs)
    @foreach ($docs->doc_user as $key1 => $users)
        @php
            $user_ids = $users->pluck("id")
        @endphp
        @foreach ($users->details as $key2 => $value2)

            //Accessing different things here

        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

and then use `$user_ids` array

Comment: Okay make sense, But how will i be able to pass it to the hidden field in the form.

Comment: Use `json_encode($user_ids)` and then pass to any input hidden