# PHP : Get values outside of foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, foreach

I have nested foreach loops in html table :

```
@foreach ($getUsers as $key => $commits)
    @foreach ($commits->getLinks as $key1 => $links)
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="" id="applicant_id" value="{{$commits->id}}">
            <td>
        <tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Next i have a form where i need the `id` of a row defined in a hidden field in foreach loop above.

**Below in the form i have have another hidden input field** where i am p**ushing the foreach hidden filed value** into the form hidden field value **but it always gives only one id (same id for every table row)**.

> Jquery for getting id from foreach hidden input **to** form hidden input :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var applicant_id = $('#applicant_id').val();
        $("#applicant").val(applicant_id);
    })
```

> Form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{route('upload-agreement')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="hidden" name="applicant" id="applicant" >
    <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" required="">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

**Issue :** The above method gives me always same `id`.

Comment: You are using `$commits` variable that doesn't changed over inner loop thats the reason i think, and you are using id of the field in jquery that always return the same value.

Comment: Did you tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46110516/2815635 as I suggested before?

Comment: You cannot have the same `id` attribute appear several times on your page, it has to be unique. You should append a variable to it in the loop in order to make it unique across the page

Comment: @SagarGautam No the loops goes through all `$commits` because `$commits` have inner object of `getLinks` like `$commits->getLinks`.

Comment: `@foreach ($commits->getLinks as $key1 => $links)` means the `$commits->id` will always be the same for n `$links`.

Comment: @Comrade you are using `commits->id` as hidden input value inside inner loop which is constant over the inner loop

Comment: @user2486 Yes i have tried that, That didn't worked apparently, And sorry for not informing you there, I thought that question wasn't fully explained.

Comment: @Calimero Spare a minute please, Explain your method in an answer please.

Comment: `id="applicant_id"` doesn't work either: ID's cannot be the same

Comment: @KDOT `id's` are not the same, They are from the database and from `auto_inrement`.

Comment: do you only have one form?  cuz if so youre gonna need some button or something to click, to pass the ID to the form.

Comment: @Kylek Yes i have one form below the foreach. Foreach have only standalone hidden input for getting the id of the iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment, and the fact you only have one form.  You need to dynamically load it with the correct ID by providing a button or something for the user to click on.

```
@foreach ($getUsers as $key => $commits)
  @foreach ($commits->getLinks as $key1 => $links)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button class="edit" data-id="{{$commits->id}}" >Edit</button>
        <td>
    <tr>
  @endforeach
@endforeach


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.edit').click(function(){
        $("#applicant").val($(this).data('id'));
    });
});
```

I would also put your form in a modal window of sorts...so you can have it pop up when you click, so that it provides an interactive easy to follow user experience.

I've provided an example. (requires Bootstrap framework)

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.edit').click(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal({backdrop:'static'});
        $("#applicant").val($(this).data('id'));
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Upload File</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{route('upload-agreement')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {{csrf_field()}}
       <input type="hidden" name="applicant" id="applicant" >
       <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" required="">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are looping through an array yet creating an input inside each iteration with the same id, instead of id set the input classname or data-attribute that can happily co exist in the dom, ids should be unique and when you select element with id there should only be one or you may get the wrong one

Comment: You mean, I should give unique id to the `applicant_id` in the foreach hidden input ?

Comment: the id of every input element in your example is given as applicant_id so if you had 10 items you would have 10 elements with this id although they would all have different values so when you use $("#applicant_id").val () it will only pick one and, regardless of your violation of DOM integrity, you are not controlling which one to pick.

Comment: the use case of your form is a little unclear, how is the form supposed to know which value to submit when there are 10 values on the page

Answer (score 1):

As the html spec says :

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

You wouldn't want your database records to have duplicate ids within a table, would you ? Well, same rule of thumb applies to HTML elements within a page. This is especially important to keep in mind while looping over database items for display, when you intend on interacting with them later on.

In your case :

```
 <input type="hidden" name="" id="applicant_id" value="{{$commits->id}}">
```

You might have mistaken the id and name attributes of the input element here. The name attribute is used to associate a name to the value when the parent form is submitted. The id attribute is just what it says it is - an identifier meant to be unique, useful for css styling or javascript manipulation (through the `document.getElementById()` method or its jQuery counterpart, `$('#FindThisIdForMe')`).

Having duplicate id values across the dom might be harmless but still makes your html invalid, and might break element retrieving (since the method which is supposed to, as the name implies, retrieve an element or nothing, has to deal with multiple candidates instead).

Appending some kind of variable to the id attribute value resolves the issue, e.g. :

```
 <input type="hidden" name="" id="applicant_id_{{$commits->id}}" value="{{$commits->id}}">
```

And fixing the jQuery selector acordingly.

You might, or might not, want to set the `name` attribute of your hidden input to the same value, depending on whether you intend to submit the form or not.

Comment: Best ever explanation... What will be the best way to fix the `jQuery selector` ?

Comment: Sorry, I was short on time to finish the answer properly. Fortunately you got another helpful answer in the meantime. Best of luck with your project.

Comment: Yeah the above answer is great, Thanks to @KyleK, By the way your answer was very useful.